# Google Analytics - how to track multiple sections of a site at once?

Tags: google, url, analytics, statistics

I need to track the pageviews and goal completions for the Blogs section of my website, and I used to do this simply by searching the word "/blog/" under Content, which would pull all of our Blog pages that had the word "/blog/" in the URL and analyze the pages together in a group. The blog URLs were always something like www.mysite.com/blog/article1.

However, we recently changed our URL naming scheme and now all blog pages have URLs that look like www.mysite.com/community/article1. Since there's no word the two formats have in common, I can no longer do a simple search like I used to. How can I run some kind of report or filter that will pull the pageviews for both /blog/ pages and /community/ pages all at once? I tried making an advanced segment but it pulled weird pages that I didn't want at all.

Any help would be MUCHLY appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried advanced segment [Include] [Page] [Begins With] "/news/" Add 'OR' Statement [Include] [Page] [Begins With] "/community/"?

Comment: The advanced segment I created just had [Contains] instead of [Begins With]... but I've now tried it both ways, and either way it seems to be returning pages from totally different sections of the site that I do not want. Am I missing something?

Comment: are you sure the rules are included and not excluded, and are bound with OR statement? What do you get as output?

Comment: The rules I specified are Include > Page > Begins With > /community/
OR
Include > Page > Begins With > /blog/

The output includes the blog and community pages, but it also includes pages from totally different directories that don't even have blog or community in their URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Oops, after a brief research I've found out that advanced segment is apparently for sessions ( [Custom Advanced Segment (based on URL) in Google Analytics not working properly?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21832/custom-advanced-segment-based-on-url-in-google-analytics-not-working-properly) ).  So any page that a person at some point have visited your /blog/ or /community/ section will be counted in, that's why the weird results. To get the result you want, create a "custom report". As you cannot use an OR condition there, you will need to enter a RegEx: ^/(blog|community)/.*$
Good stuff that you have asked your question, today I've learned something new!

Answer (score -1):

Use [Google Tag manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) which count all of your events.

Comment: Such a short answer is not high quality.  Please edit this answer to explain more.  What setup is needed in Google Tag manager?  How does GTM provide a solution to this specific problem?  What section of the documentation covers tracking multiple sections of the site at once?